# US citizen driving his car with a Mexican license

Tags: usa, us-citizens, driving-licenses

My son is a US citizen but has a Mexican driver's license. Can he drive in the US?

Answer (score 14):

Mexican driver's licenses are recognized in the US without regard to the citizenship of the bearer.

Most US states if not all require new residents to obtain a driver's license from that state within a certain time of establishing residence (I expect that in most cases it's 30 or 60 days) to be able to drive legally in that state.  If your son resides in the US, police in his state of residence may refuse to recognize the Mexican license as valid and may therefore cite him as an unlicensed driver.  If your son resides in Mexico then there should be no problem.

Comment: To be clear, you are referring to the difference between citizenship (U.S.) and residency (may be Mexican). The key is *residency,*, i.e. where you pay your bills and *live.* Foreign drivers licenses can generally only be used legally by *non-residents,* after some grace period.